# Does URLEncodedUtils.parse() presever the order?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Does [URLEncodedUtils.parse(uri, encoding)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#parse%28java.net.URI,%20java.lang.String%29) return the parameters in the same order mentioned in the URL?
And does it return all the values for parameters with duplicate names?

Comment: If you have a look at the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.java.html) of the function (line 160 and following), yes. But you shouldn't depend on implementation details. If it is not documented, you can't rely on it.

Comment: thank you! can you please add your comment as an answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void parse (
       final List <NameValuePair> parameters, 
       final Scanner scanner, 
       final String encoding) {
   scanner.useDelimiter(PARAMETER_SEPARATOR);
   while (scanner.hasNext()) {
       final String[] nameValue = scanner.next().split(NAME_VALUE_SEPARATOR);
       if (nameValue.length == 0 || nameValue.length > 2)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad parameter");

        final String name = decode(nameValue[0], encoding);
        String value = null;
       if (nameValue.length == 2)
           value = decode(nameValue[1], encoding);
       parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
   }
}
```

As you can see in the parse-function, it preserves the order of the parameters in the URL. But this is an implementation detail and not documented, so it can change without warning. You really should not rely on that behavior in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since it returns a list, it should return the name-value pairs in order and should also return duplicates.

However, you shouldn't rely on the order of the parameters but rather access them via their names.
Duplicates would be bad anyways, i.e. what would a `lang=en&lang=de` mean? If you need a list you'd better do something like `languages=en,de` or provide better parameter names.

Comment: my program requires to handle duplicates and the order of parameters.

Comment: @adranale could you elaborate on why? Might there be a problem with the design?